# NLOG varialble fileName and archiveFIleName

Tags: nlog

I have a generic target with a fileName ${logger}.csv.  Is it possible for archiveFileName to use this same ${logger} in the archiveFileName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use any ${variable} as many times as you want.

```
...
archiveFileName="${logger}.{#####}.csv"
...
```

Take look at **[Archival options](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archival-options)** and **[Size/time-based file archival](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target#size-based-file-archival)** in the NLog documentation for more information